# Get number of unique users who played a certain artist

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that contains UserID's ArtistID's and weights (aka play counts) for users of the service lastFM. I have done the following to group the data frame by the artistID to see which users are playing them

```py
user_artists = pd.read_csv('user_artists.csv', delim = '\t')

group_by_artist = user_artists.groupby(["artistID","userID"])
```

and when I call `group_by_artist.first()` I get a table that looks like this.

[image: GroupBy table]

This is partially what I need however, the main goal is to get HOW MANY unique users played each artist and then plot it, is there any way I can go from this information to procure the desired information? Maybe by another groupby and then plot the number of unique users per artist on a bar graph?

Comment: `user_artist.groupby('artistID').userID.nunique()`?

Comment: oh ok so I don't need to do the groupby artistID then userID